# Difficulty in passing JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, response

I'm unable to parse `JSON`. My `JSON` snippet returned from `requests.post` response :-

```
{'result': {'parent': '', 'reason': '', 'made_sla': 'true', 'backout_plan': '', 'watch_list': '', 'upon_reject': 'cancel', 'sys_updated_on': '2018-08-22 11:16:09', 'type': 'Comprehensive', 'conflict_status': 'Not Run', 'approval_history': '', 'number': 'CHG0030006', 'test_plan': '', 'cab_delegate': '', 'sys_updated_by': 'admin', 'opened_by': {'link': 'https://dev65345.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441', 'value': '6816f79cc0a8016401c5a33be04be441'}, 'user_input': '', 'requested_by_date': '', 'sys_created_on': '2018-08-22 11:16:09', 'sys_domain': {'link': 'https://dev65345.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/global', 'value': 'global'}, 'state': '-5', 'sys_created_by': 'admin', 'knowledge': 'false', 'order': '', 'phase': 'requested', 'closed_at': '', 'cmdb_ci': '', 'delivery_plan': '', 'impact': '3', 'active': 'true', 'review_comments': '', 'work_notes_list': '', 'business_service': '', 'priority': '4', 'sys_domain_path': '/', 'time_worked': '', 'cab_recommendation': '', 'expected_start': '', 'production_system': 'false', 'opened_at': '2018-08-22 11:16:09', 'review_date': '', 'business_duration': '', 'group_list': '', 'requested_by': {'link': 'https://dev6345.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user/user1', 'value': 'user1'}, 'work_end': '', 'change_plan': '', 'phase_state': 'open', 'approval_set': '', 'cab_date': '', 'work_notes': '', 'implementation_plan': '', 'end_date': '', 'short_description': '', 'close_code': '', 'correlation_display': '', 'delivery_task': '', 'work_start': '', 'assignment_group': {'link': 'https://dev65345.service-now.com/api/now/table/sys_user_group/testgroup', 'value': 'testgroup'}, 'additional_assignee_list': '', 'outside_maintenance_schedule': 'false', 'description': '', 'on_hold_reason': '', 'calendar_duration': '', 'std_change_producer_version': '', 'close_notes': '', 'sys_class_name': 'change_request', 'closed_by': '', 'follow_up': '', 'sys_id': '436eda82db4023008e357a61399619ee', 'contact_type': '', 'cab_required': 'false', 'urgency': '3', 'scope': '3', 'company': '', 'justification': '', 'reassignment_count': '0', 'review_status': '', 'activity_due': '', 'assigned_to': '', 'start_date': '', 'comments': '', 'approval': 'requested', 'sla_due': '', 'comments_and_work_notes': '', 'due_date': '', 'sys_mod_count': '0', 'on_hold': 'false', 'sys_tags': '', 'conflict_last_run': '', 'escalation': '0', 'upon_approval': 'proceed', 'correlation_id': '', 'location': '', 'risk': '3', 'category': 'Other', 'risk_impact_analysis': ''}}
```

I searched on the net. It is showing as as it is single quotes it's not parsing.

So I tried to convert the single quotes into double quotes.

```
with open ('output.json','r') as handle:
  handle=open('output.json')
str="123"
str=handle.stringify() #also with .str()
str = str.replace("\'", "\"")
jsonobj=json.load(json.dumps(handle))
```

But it shows me `No attribute stringify or str` as it is an `json` object and these are string object function. So, can you please help me with what is the correct way of parsing the `json` object with single quotes in a file.

The code:-

```
import requests
import json
from pprint import pprint

print("hello world")

url="********"

user="****"
password="*****"
headers={"Content-Type":"application/xml","Accept":"application/json"}

#response=requests.get(url,auth=(user,password),headers=headers)
response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, password), headers=headers ,data="******in xml****")

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())

jsonobj=json.load(json.dumps(response.json()))
pprint(jsonobj)
```

Comment: *"requests.post response"* – Are you sure that's supposed to be JSON, and not a Python dict?

Comment: @deceze but in header i have specified json

Comment: Unrelated, but `handle` is already an opened file by the time you try to open the same file again.

Comment: In what header have you specified JSON where? Show us the code that produces this in the first place, not your attempts to decode it.

Comment: `json.load(json.dumps(response.json()))` parses JSON into a dict then encodes it to JSON then parses it again to a dict (incorrectly, as it should be `loads`, not `load`)…

Comment: also tried with load as load is for file correct and loads is for string.SO i am getting a dictionary not an json object correct.that is that i can directly traverse the directory.am i right....

Comment: Make that `jsonobj=response.json()`

Comment: @L3viathan ok trying and will let u know asap

Comment: @L3viathan it's working

Comment: @L3viathan so now i can directly traverse as a dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you receive from `requests.post` is not JSON, it's a dictionary.

One that can be *encoded* in JSON, via `json.dumps(result)`.

JSON is a text format to *represent* objects (the "ON" means "object notation"). You can convert a dictionary (or list or scalar) into a JSON-encoded string, or the other way around.

What `requests.post` does is taking the JSON response and already parsing it (with `json.loads`), so you don't have to think about JSON at all.

Comment: Ok,I'll try and let you know asap

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown the code where you get the data from the post. However, you are almost certainly doing something like this:

```
response = requests.post('...')
data = response.json()
```

Here `data` is *already* parsed from JSON to a Python dict; that is what the requests `json` method does. There is no need to parse it again.

If you need raw JSON rather than Python data, then don't call the `json` method. Get the data direct from the response:

```
data = response.content
```

Now `data` will be a string containing JSON.